# PYTHONPATH not included in sys.path on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, linux, bash

After struggling with this for quite a few hours I am at my wit's end.

I want to include the Python modules from my project into the PYTHONPATH, so that the Python interpreter can resolve them and make them available for `import`.

My project folder looks like this:

```
my_project/
  module1/
    __init__.py
    module1.py
  module2/
    __init__.py
    module2.py
```

I've exported PYTHONPATH in `/etc/bash.bashrc` like this:

```
PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/john/my_project/"
```

After restarting my shell I can echo it:

```
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
:/home/john/my_project/
```

Then I fire up a Python command line and look at what `sys.path` became:

```
$ source /home/john/my_env/bin/activate
(my_env)$ python3
>>> import os
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/john/my_env/lib/python35.zip', '/home/john/my_env/lib/python3.5', '/home/john/my_env/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/home/john/my_env/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/home/john/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
```

As you can clearly see, `/home/john/my_project/` wasn't included and `import module1` will fail.

The last thing I can think of is that Python can't see my PYTHONPATH variable, hence not adding it's content to `sys.path`.

Do you guys find my mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nicely presented, thus the upvote. Alas, a duplicate, thus the close. The keyword you missed in your search was probably `virtualenv`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you can see from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables):

Use `export` in bash to set variables for the current shell and for all processes spawned from the current shell. So you should use:

`export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/john/my_project/"`

Comment: Oh my god, such a stupid mistake. I didn't even notice that slip when writing this question. Guess I went full tilt on the matter. Thanks!

Comment: @FlorianBraun no problem it happens :)